# Display sqlite3 database in datagridview c++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, datagridview, sqlite

I'm trying to populate a table in a datagridview from a SQL database.

I have seen a lot of code in C# but not in C++, and I'm using SQLite3.

So far I can print out to console using the example from [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm)

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The question: is it possible in C++ to add rows like the example code prints out?

I saw this [guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_cj1uhs9-c) do something like it but he uses another sql lib and I can't figure out how to make this work for SQLite(3).

Comment: Use a [cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/19406/reading-data-from-a-cursor) instead.

Comment: Why are you using C++/CLI to begin with? And since you do, why aren't you using a .NET wrapper for SQLite instead of the native C interface?

Comment: @IInspectable I use C++ because I wanted to learn C++. I see that it might have been a not so vise choice to use the native C for SQLite, can you suggest a good .NET wrapper?

Comment: C++/CLI is **not** C++. You really have to make up your mind, based on facts not assumptions. If you do want to use C++, I would recommend Kenny Kerr's Visual Studio Magazine article [Using SQLite with Modern C++](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/02/01/using-sqlite-with-modern-c.aspx). Depending on how you are learning, going with plain C may also be a viable option. It'll teach you a lot of important lessons that are relevant in **any** programming language.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the article. I have done a lot already in C++. The program started as a command line program the I added forms to it so that is Why I say it'c C++/ CLI. I will read the article through and look in to changing to plain C.

Comment: *The* standard windowing component in Windows is all unmanaged code, with a native interface. There is no requirement to pull in a .NET dependency, just because you need a UI. Documentation starts here: [windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595.aspx).